# SQL Convert BigInt 'Ticks' to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

The query shown below selects all active jobs and shows the following in the cell for each phase

```
EstimatedTime / ActualTime.
(HH:MM)
```

This did work when ActualTime and EstimatedTime was a time(7), but I have since changed its type to a BigInt and storing TimeSpan.Ticks;

How can I modify this query to show according to the above format? It must be done on the SQL level and not when being displayed due to the fact the datagrid displays exactly what SQL pulls in.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + ID + ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                  FROM JobPhases
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM    
(   
    SELECT j.JobID as ''JobNumber'', c.Registration as ''Reg.'', p.Name, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, ''0:00:00'', j.EstimatedTime)), ''00:00:00'') AS TIME), 108) + ''/'' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, ''0:00:00'', j.ActualTime)), ''00:00:00'') AS TIME), 108) as [x]
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases p ON p.ID = j.PhaseId
    INNER JOIN Jobs job on job.ID = j.JobID
    INNER JOIN Cars c on job.CarID = c.ID
    WHERE (job.Status = 1 or job.Status = 0)
    GROUP BY c.Registration, p.Name, j.JobID
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   MAX(x)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) pvt'

execute(@query);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The result of `Time / Time` doesn't have a unit of time *(For example, 6 meters squared, divided by 2 meters, yields a result of 3 meters => m2 / m = m.  5 miles / 0.5 hours = 10 miles/hour. 6 hours / 3 hours = 2, with no units.)*.  What is this meant to be showing?

Comment: "10:00/11:32" where 10:00 is the Estimated Time and 11:32 is the actual time taken.

Comment: But what is the result?  `10:00 / 11:32 = 600 minutes / 692 minutes = 0.86705...` or `36000 seconds / 41520 seconds = 0.86705`  It's NOT a time, it has no units of any kind, it's a ratio...`

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. The result is a simple string displaying the estimated time and actual time taken on a job. This was a time(7) but have had to replace this with a BigInt due to the fact time(7) stored an actual time rather than a 'counter'. C# can convert TimeSpan Ticks using TimeSpan.FromTicks(), I basically need an SQL equivalent.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you confused the question by adding too much unrelated information, and so I focussed on the wrong thing, sorry.  If all you need is to create a `time` from a `bigint` then use `DATEADD(ns, CAST(0 AS TIME(7)), @ticks * 100)` or `DATEADD(mcs, CAST(0 AS TIME(7)), @ticks / 10)`, etc, etc?